# lw_geom_to_geojson: 'CompoundCurve' geometry not supported

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geojson, geometry

I am using PostgreSQL 14 with PosGIS 3.1.4. The trigger below is is logging changes before INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE to any of the tables.

```
   BEGIN
     IF TG_OP = 'INSERT'
     THEN INSERT INTO schema.table_history (tablename, schemaname, operation, new_val) 
          VALUES (TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, row_to_json(NEW));
          RETURN NEW;
     ELSIF  TG_OP = 'UPDATE'
     THEN INSERT INTO schema.table_history (tablename, schemaname, operation, new_value, old_value)
          VALUES (TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, row_to_json(NEW), row_to_json(OLD));
          RETURN NEW;
     ELSIF TG_OP = 'DELETE'
     THEN INSERT INTO schema.table_history(tablename, schemaname, operation, old_value)
          VALUES (TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, row_to_json(OLD));
          RETURN OLD;
     END IF;
   END;
```

One of my tables is using the CompoundCurveZM geometry and i get this error:
`lwgeom_to_geojson: 'CompoundCurve' geometry type not supported`
It looks like row_to_json() is calling lwgeom_to_geojson().

1. Is there a workaround to store CompoundCurveZM geometries as geojson?
2. If there is no workaround, is there a method to store my rows as json without calling lw_geom_togeojson() as part of row_to_json()?

This, from @user30184, is working when applied to the table with the curved geometry.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mytrigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
    new_record record;
    old_record record;     
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        ST_Force3DZ(ST_CurveToLine(NEW.CurvedGeometry)) as LineGeometry,
        NEW.column2,
        NEW.column3,
        ... into new_record
    FROM my_table;
    SELECT 
        ST_Force3DZ(ST_CurveToLine(OLD.CurvedGeometry)) as LineGeometry,
        OLD.column2,
        OLD.column3,
        ... into old_record
    FROM my_table;              

IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN 
    INSERT INTO schema.table_history (tabname, schemaname, operation, new_value)
    VALUES (TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA,TG_OP, row_to_json(new_record));
RETURN NEW;
ELSIF  TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
    INSERT INTO schema.table_history (tabname, schemaname, operation, new_value, old_value)
    VALUES (TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, row_to_json(new_record), row_to_json(old_record));
    RETURN NEW;
ELSIF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
    INSERT INTO schema.table_history (tabname, schemaname, operation, old_value)
    VALUES (TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, row_to_json(old_record));
    RETURN OLD;
END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GeoJSON specification does not allow curved geometries. See https://geojson.org/

> GeoJSON supports the following geometry types: Point, LineString,
> Polygon, MultiPoint, MultiLineString, and MultiPolygon.

You must convert the curved geometries into linear ones and it is probably easiest for you to use the PostGIS function ST_CurveToLine https://postgis.net/docs/ST_CurveToLine.html

> Converts a CIRCULAR STRING to regular LINESTRING or CURVEPOLYGON to
> POLYGON or MULTISURFACE to MULTIPOLYGON. Useful for outputting to
> devices that can't support CIRCULARSTRING geometry types

CompoundCurve is not mentioned in the documentation but hopefully it is still supported. Notice also that GeoJSON supports only XY and XYZ geometries so you must drop the M from your CompoundCurveZM. You can do it with ST_Force3DZ https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Force_3DZ.html.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I just adjusted my trigger function a little bit.